# BigQuery Query with Edit Distance UDF Throws Error

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, sql

I am trying to use compare the content among articles using edit distance algorithm. I create a UDF in the Standard Query. It works fine when number of articles are small (such as 10 articles, total comparison is be 10X10 = 100).

If the total number of articles is big, like 100 (total comparison is 100 x 100 =  10000). BigQuery UI throws the following error:

Error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
Job ID: newspapers-142716:US.bquijob_cfbb316_161c359b4ec

I wonder if it is because BigQuery can't handle that much amount of data when calling the UDF. The Edit Distance algorithm is not "cheap" operation, could that the reason too?

Is using the UDF for this purpose the right approach? Any other alternatives?

Below is my UDF code:

```js
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION
  editDistance(a STRING, b STRING)
  RETURNS FLOAT64
  LANGUAGE js 
  AS 
"""
  if(a.length == 0) return b.length; 
  if(b.length == 0) return a.length; 

  var matrix = [];

  // increment along the first column of each row
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i <= b.length; i++){
    matrix[i] = [i];
  }

  // increment each column in the first row
  var j;
  for(j = 0; j <= a.length; j++){
    matrix[0][j] = j;
  }

  // Fill in the rest of the matrix
  for(i = 1; i <= b.length; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= a.length; j++){
      if(b.charAt(i-1) == a.charAt(j-1)){
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1];
      } else {
        matrix[i][j] = Math.min(matrix[i-1][j-1] + 1, // substitution
                                Math.min(matrix[i][j-1] + 1, // insertion
                                         matrix[i-1][j] + 1)); // deletion
      }
    }
  }

  distance = matrix[b.length][a.length]
  
  return distance/Math.max(a.length, b.length)
  
  //return matrix[b.length][a.length];
    
"""
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if it is because BigQuery can't handle that much amount of
>   data when calling the UDF.

You are right - the actual error for your job was

> Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

I suppose every article is quite long, probably few KBs, so `matrix` that you build inside function is several MBs.
This type of `CROSS JOIN` processing is probably better suited for DataFlow or some other batch tool. To do it in BigQuery, you will need to break the table into smaller pieces, or to run each article against every other article as a separate query (but this will result in multiple scans, and can be costly).

Comment: Thanks Mosha. We use a lot of Google products/services in our company. I will look into DataFlow and/or try other solutions